# Node path - change root path upon requiring module

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, path, require

I am working on an express subapp system for a project and want to include whole express apps saved within a directory for use within a larger project. So far, I have established a "master" express app which runs multiple "slave" subapps using `express.use(...)`. However, when I require these "slave" subapps, any paths resolved using `./` uses the `./` of the "master". Consequently, subapp paths cannot be resolved unless `./` is removed.

Here is a demo of how my master and slave express apps are organised: [Demo tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yULN1.png)

If I require `slave.js` within `master.js` and call `path.resolve("./index.html")` within `slave.js` it returns the path `root/index.html` - which doesn't exist. I acknowledge that this is expected behaviour.

However, I am seeking a way to return `root/subapps/index.html` without resorting to `path.resolve("index.html")`, as indeed I know that `path.resolve("index.html")` within `slave.js` returns `root/subapps/index.html`.

The reason I'm seeking this is so I can build apps in a testing environment and then deploy them as "slave" apps for use within a "master" app, without having to change relative paths.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use in your slave app `path.resolve(__dirname, "index.html")`

Comment: Thanks, I tried that before and am still wondering if there's another way?